# How to apply conditional style when group changes?

Tags: jasper-reports

There are lots of tutorials on how to zebra stripe the **rows** of a report. Like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| Value | Color |
+-------+-------+
| A     | white |
| A     | black |
| B     | white |
| B     | black |
| B     | white |
| C     | black |
| D     | white |
| D     | black |
+-------+-------+
```

But what I want to do is a **grouped stripping**. Like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| Value | Color |
+-------+-------+
| A     | white |
| A     | white |
| B     | black |
| B     | black |
| B     | black |
| C     | white |
| D     | black |
| D     | black |
+-------+-------+
```

I'm using the column "Value" as the expression of a group and my data is sorted by "Value". "black" is a black rectangle to be printed when the group is black. "white" is the absence of the black rectangle. I want a variable that I can put in "Print When Expression" of the black rectangle.

What I've tried until now:

- Create a variable $V{print}
- Initial Value Expression: false
- Variable Expression: !$V{print}
- Increment type: Group
- Increment group: Value

I expected the value of $V{print} to change to it's opposite value every time the group changed. What I get is the normal striped list (black, white, black, white...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with you current solution is:

```xml
calculationType="Nothing"
```

> **Nothing**: This is the default calculation type that a variable performs. It means that the variable's value is recalculated with every iteration in the data source and that the value returned is obtained by **simply evaluating the variable's expression**.

This type of calculation will invalidate your `incrementType`, hence the `incrementType` has no effect, since we are not calculating. This is why currently you get black,white,black,white.

This will achieve your desired result

**Variable definition** (*lets do some calculation example increment by 1 every time group change, sum or count*)

```xml
<variable name="GroupCnt" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="myGroup" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

**conditionExpression** (*we can use modulus operator the variable `GroupCnt`*)

```xml
<conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{GroupCnt}%2==0]]></conditionExpression>
```

**Example of complete jrxml** (I have added an rectangle as OP comment on this)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="group" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c1d9b4b7-6162-4b17-b871-3cf3b867d1ef">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="myStyle">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{GroupCnt}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#000000"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <field name="Value" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="GroupCnt" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="myGroup" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="myGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{Value}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="myStyle" x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="7ca1ac35-6249-4ba6-ac87-031f8d410d2e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement style="myStyle" x="150" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="d322e0df-0d39-4370-90e6-58305d449852"/>
            </rectangle>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

*`new Boolean($V{GroupCnt}.intValue()%2==0)`, `new Boolean` and `intValue()` is just use to be compatibile with old jasper report versions it is not needed in latest versions*

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: I believe my variable $V{print} could be used in your <conditionalStyle>. Cause in the end they use group increment and results in a Boolean.
I think the problem in using rectangles is that they have no "evaluation time" like text fields do. Is the expression in <conditionalStyle> evaluated when the text field is evaluated?

Comment: @Gustavo As far as your current solution with calculationType="Nothing"" I have edit the answer so you can see why this why will not work (invalidates incrementType)

Comment: @Gustavo Regarding evaluationTime I can not see how this is relative to the question since it is not needed (should be now), my above example with a rectangle would produce same result. (I have update answer also on this)

Comment: Since I don't need the number of times the group changed, I tried to use a `Boolean` variable. But since there is no `AND`, `OR` or `NOT` calculation, I set calculation to `nothing` and made the "calculation" in the expression. I didn't know that calculation `nothing` would invalidate `incrementType`. In fact I still don't get or agree with this behavior. Anyway, thanks. It worked pretty fine and the conditional style (over the rectangle) solution is a plus.

Comment: 1) JasperReports Schema Reference: "_incrementType: Increment level for variables that perform calculations_".

2) The JasperReports Ultimate Guide: _INCREMENT TYPE: This property lets you choose the exact moment to increment the variable..._.

3) iReport property comment: _Increment Type: When the variable expression should be evaluated to get a new value_.

The first reference is exactly what you said. The other two are how I used to think of increment type.

Comment: The key word is *increment*, hence not written *evaluate*, indicating that it has to do with your calculation. So no calculation, no increment...

Comment: The basic difference is that the evalutationTime is set on the textField.... and in your case it was now... so it was evaluating with no calculation on every row.

Comment: I think _...the exact moment..._ and _When..._ in the above references mislead me. I completely agree that *increment* doesn't sound like a time thing.